# Can I SSH from Mac to Linux, with Linux windows opening on the Mac?

Tags: linux, mac, ssh, x-windows

This is a question about X Windows support for Mac.

I sometimes ssh to a Linux computer, and start software there.

The software requires graphical interface (a DISPLAY).

I am curious whether it is possible to direct all graphical output from  the Linux machine to my local Mac computer that I use for sshing to the Linux machine.

Answer (score 6):

You can X-tunnel over ssh on a mac; OS X machines all have an X server installed by default.  You need to use the command `ssh -X [hostname]` to enable the X-tunnel, and then start the program via the shell.  Typically, you do not need to specify your local display; the program should display locally automatically.

Comment: This might also need `X11Forwarding yes` in `sshd_config` on your Linux box.

Comment: Some servers will only allow trusted connections, if so use `ssh -Y`. (or put `ForwardX11Trusted Yes` into ~/ssh/config for this host)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, yes it is. According to [Apple](http://developer.apple.com/opensource/tools/x11.html) it is optional but installed by default. There's also [Xquartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/wiki)